# Is the "Latin Language" section more than just Latin?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to the Latin Language forum here. But, I'm a little surprised to see how many posts there are about Greek.  Is this a Latin + Greek place to ask questions? Or is it that the questions are being allowed by the moderators since there's no better place to ask the Greek questions?

Comment: This is a question for the Meta StackExchange, not here. And, yes, Greek questions are allowed here, especially questions about the relationship between Greek and Latin. Greek and Latin are related and they interacted a lot in antiquity (many loanwords). The questions about Etruscan are also allowed.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some vital context.

Comment: Here is the [policy](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions) in effect.

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as duplicate since it's already been answered. Feel free to comment on the links question or join us in our chat room if you have further questions about this.

Comment: @cmw Since this is a duplicate and since the question has been closed, what the proper procedure from here? Should I just delete the question? Or is there a different way of marking it as "taken care of"?

Comment: @Epimanes Nah, no need really. For whatever reason, we don't tend to delete duplicate threads. In case anyone finds this thread in the future, the links will serve to direct them to the earlier discussion.

Comment: And if you needed a site precedence for it, [here it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates).